# How to edit/update timeseries data with a timestamp using thingsboard widget action

Tags: widget, dashboard, thingsboard

I want to edit/update timeseries data from thingsboard Timeseries table widget using widget action with html. But I only change the latest timeseries data. I need to update/edit timeseries data with a specific timestamp.

I have tried to use thingsboard widget action with html code in thingsboard widget action features and able to update the latet timeseries data but can't update historical values with a specific timestamps.